# ng-repeat not working while traversing JavaScript array of objects

Tags: javascript, php, html, arrays, angularjs

This is my controller code

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);
myApp.controller('restaurantController',['$scope','$http', function($scope, $http){
    $http.get($scope.something).success(function (data){
        $scope.items = data;
    });
    $scope.orders = [];
    $scope.process = function(item){
        var cart = '{"name":"'+item.name+'","price":"'+item.quantity*parseInt(item.price)+'","quantity":"'+item.quantity+'"}';
        $scope.orders.push(cart);
    }
}]);
```

Basically I have a PHP page where I am getting the user values and dynamically adding elements to the $scope.orders array.

And then to display the elements of array I am using this code

```
<div class="container" ng-repeat="order in orders">
    <h3>{{order.name}}</h3>
</div>
```

In my PHP page.But nothing being displayed.

Comment: Because `cart` is a **string**, not _object_

Comment: Problem is not because of String. you are not sending item from DOM or if you want to set it from items which you already called in success callback then use forEach loop for seperate entries of item

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be careful you're not pushing object in your `$scope.orders` Array, you're pushing stringified version of your object.

Unlike PHP, JavaScript interpret and nows how to use and browse through JSON objects. Try this :

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('restaurantController',['$scope','$http', function($scope, $http){
  $scope.orders = [];

  $http.get($scope.something)    // .success() is deprecated use .then() instead
    .then(function ( data ) {
      $scope.items = data;
    },
    function ( err ) {
      $scope.items = [];
    });

  $scope.process = function(item){
    var cart = { 
      name      : item.name,
      price     : item.quantity * parseFloat(item.price), 
      quantity  : item.quantity 
    };

    // Use .parseFLoat() because item price may not be an integer

    $scope.orders.push(cart);
  }
}]);
```

Then you'll be able to loop over `$scope.orders` Array.

Comment: Thank you its working.I didnt notice that I am passing a string.